# Everything moves when I change one thing

Tags: modeling, objects, vertices

I'm modeling a car and it's almost complete except now whenever I move one vertex the whole model changes. Parts of it jut out whenever I extrude or make anything. I tried building tires separately and when I went to use bullion to union everything the entire model disappeared. Ctrl z brought it back of and sometimes if I undo and then redo the model will look fine but while working everything shifts randomly.

Comment: *Proportional Edit* turned on? See: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/proportional_edit.html